# Missing comma in SQL command

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following query for inserting values into myemp table:

```
insert into myemp(employee_id,first_name,last_name,hire_date)
  values(1001,'dato,'datuashvili','01-03-05');
```

after running it writes

```
Error starting at line 7 in command:
insert into myemp(employee_id,first_name,last_name,hire_date) 
  values(1001,'dato,'datuashvili','01-03-05'); 
Error at Command Line:8 Column:21
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00917: missing comma
00917. 00000 -  "missing comma"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

but I can't understand where I missed a comma.

Comment: It appears as you has not made enough research for solve your problem

Comment: A good syntax highlighter can be very helpful...

Answer (score 7):

try this

```
insert into myemp(employee_id,first_name,last_name,hire_date)
  values(1001,'dato','datuashvili','01-03-05');
```

' was missing after dato

Answer (score 4):

You've missed a `'` after `dato`, that is why you've got the error.

Answer (score 2):

I think you missing a single quote for dato . ie, it must be

```
insert into myemp(employee_id,first_name,last_name,hire_date) 
  values(1001,'dato','datuashvili','01-03-05');
```

Answer (score 1):

it should be like this

```
insert into myemp(employee_id,first_name,last_name,hire_date)   values(1001,'dato','datuashvili','01-03-05');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
insert into myemp(employee_id,first_name,last_name,hire_date) 
  values(1001,**'dato,**'datuashvili','01-03-05');
```

It can be the appostrophe write

```
insert into myemp(employee_id,first_name,last_name,hire_date) 
  values(1001,'dato','datuashvili','01-03-05');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 insert into myemp(employee_id,first_name,last_name,hire_date)  
 values(1001,'dato,'datuashvili','01-03-05');
```

should be

```
insert into myemp(employee_id,first_name,last_name,hire_date)
  values(1001,'dato','datuashvili','01-03-05');
```

you missed `'` after `dato`.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the missing quote `'`, you should look up how to use date types.

What date is the `'01-03-05'`?

Is it `1st-Mar-2005` ?

Is it `Jan-3rd-2005` ?

Is it `2001-Mar-5th` ?

Is it `1901-Mar-5th` ?

Why should the database guess? it's better to use a standard format like: `'2005-03-01'`